# execute() SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem in my code and I don't understand that!
here is the part of my code that has problem

```sql
$conn = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate FROM NEWS order by " . mysql_real_escape_string($order) . " LIMIT :numROws";
$st = $conn -> prepare($sql);
$st -> bindValue(":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$st -> execute();
```

if it is not clear please tell.

Comment: Note that all `mysql_*` functions are now deprecated, including `mysql_real_escape_string()`. You should probably rethink your logic and use something like a `switch` to insert the correct `ORDER BY` into your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might have a simple typo.

In your SQL, you write:

```
...LIMIT :numROws";
```

But then you're binding:

```
$st -> bindValue(":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

PHP is case sensitive, so :numROws and :numRows are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
$st -> bindValue(":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

with:

```
$st -> bindValue(":numROws", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```